# mongoosejs schema index required trim unique where is the reference?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

in a mongoosejs schema I can see

```
slug: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        index: true,
        trim: true
    },
```

I've looked for just a lot but
I'm not able to find a reference of all that words.
Can you help me to find it !
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All possible options you can find on this page
http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType